# Does "consumes X ammo per shot" cancel the assassin's One Shot One Kill skill?

Tags: borderlands-2

I got two new sniper rifles from the gold key chest.  One has about 7000 base damage.  The other is E-Tech "consumes 2 ammo per shot" and has a little over 10000 base damage.  When I test fire them (noscope headshots) at the dummy the 7000 base weapon does about 110k damage.  Sometimes it also causes elemental damage over time.  The 10000 base weapon does about 70k for the same shot.

The only thing I can think of is that my One Shot One Kill skill does not count on the E-Tech weapon, presumably due to "consumes 2 ammo per shot".  I have 5+4 points in that for 108% bonus damage.

(sadly the 7k base damage weapon is Dahl and thus burst while zoomed)

Comment: Easiest way to test is to respec, fill all skills the same except that one and test shoot. The e-tech snipers might deal less crit damage or something, I've heard reports of them feeling underpowered, especially the snipers

Comment: @BenBrocka: Aha, good idea, I can just remove the +4 One Shot bonus and see if that changes it.

Comment: Also, do not throw Dahl one away yet. Try to learn to let zoom go mid-burst - it might seem a hassle, but after you get a hold of it, you might have no problem firing single shots.

Comment: @OrcJMR: I have used that trick but I tend to jerk the shot.  This one bursts pretty damn fast -- the base fire rate is quite high.  I've had other sniper rifles with fire rates around 1.0 where that was easy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From my experience of the game, consuming multiple ammo per shot does not affect One Shot.

In addition, if you look at the actual text, it doesn't say "first bullet" but "first shot" so, to me that indicates that the ammo consumed has nothing to do with the skill at all.

As a slight aside, I read this online and it helped me a whole bunch, try and get the unique gun "Infinity" which can be had by farming Doc Mercy. It consumes no ammo and so the game treats it as always having 1 shot in in the clip and so, every single bullet that comes out of there is treated as the first bullet from a fully loaded magazine. Works absolute wonders with the One Shot skill.

Comment: At level 50, with a level 48 Infinity, I can do ridiculous things to enemies. And never having to reload is a huge bonus in duels and such.

Comment: Verified my theory was wrong.  Still not sure why two very similar sniper rifles do such different damage...

Comment: I've been having similar things happen with many of my guns but I never bothered investigating. Investigation is now underway :).

Just remember that many guns (especially pink/purple/orange and some blue) have unlisted extra effects. e.g. I have an E-Tech Assault Rifle that fires Shock 'bullets' and they bounce of walls a couple of times if they don't hit an enemy. This effect is not listed on the gun itself. I've confirmed that this is not a unique or legendary weapon so you never know, you could have a bonus crit or some such unlisted effect on your gun.

Answer (score 2):

If the Non-E-tech gun is a fire elemental gun it gets a damage multiplier to flesh of 1.5 in playthrough 1, and 1.75 in playthrough 2.  So if the E-tech one is non-elemental, explosive, electric, or slag it would only be times 1.  If it's corroisve its even worse and against a flesh target would be multiplied by 0.9 in Playthrough 1 or 0.6 in playthrough 2.